# c# - Export large object data to Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, linq, vsto, add-in

my program gather data from different XML files by selecting data with LINQ.
It results having below proprieties for each element of my object collections.
Each collection having arround 10k objects (with 11 proprieties), 15 collection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R1Hj.jpg

Everything's fine until i need to export them to excel file.
I'm looping each cell data as below, then this is far too long.
As describe above, there is large data to export.

```
            foreach (dataContainer elt in Liste) 
        {
            
            for(int b = 1; b <= 11; b++) 
            { 
            Excel.Range currentRange = outputWorksheet.Cells[Liste.IndexOf(elt)+2, b];
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 1: currentRange.Value2 = elt.ctNumber;break;
                    case 2: currentRange.Value2 = elt.isoType; break;
                    case 3: currentRange.Value2 = elt.bkgNumber; break;
                    case 4: currentRange.Value2 = elt.POO; break;
                    case 5: currentRange.Value2 = elt.POL; break;
                    case 6: currentRange.Value2 = elt.POD; break;
                    case 7: currentRange.Value2 = elt.OPE; break;
                    case 8: currentRange.Value2 = elt.Empty; break;
                    case 9: currentRange.Value2 = elt.flagOOG; break;
                    case 10: currentRange.Value2 = elt.teus; break;
                    case 11: currentRange.Value2 = elt.weight; break;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i improve my way to export data in excel ? Knowing i can't use .csv file.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code as properly formatted markdown instead of posting pictures of it. [Stack Overflow editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) can assist you

Comment: Is it an option to use a Database as intermediary? MSSQL can export Tables to Excel.

Comment: For exporting it is much more efficient to use the command line tool sqlcmd (or the cmdlet in powershell sqlserver which uses the sqlcmd).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: i added code that loop value to excel, but cannot paste first picture since it is properties of my objects.

Comment: i noticed some advised SQL as a solution, but isn't that weird read XML => translate SQL => paste to excel ? There is no quicker solution read XML => Write in excel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a standalone Excel file instead of updating the one currently being displayed, directly creating the file using Open XML SDK rather than Excel Object Model would be faster - start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/spreadsheets

Comment: unfortunately, i'll have to use a standard excel file for the rest of the process, cannot create an empty excel file

Comment: Open XML SDK allows to edit an existing file. It just cannot edit a file that Excel is already showing.

Answer (score 0):

After few research, i found out the best way to proceed for my case, very quick method.
I create a an object that will contains my 2D data, then assign an excel range value  = to this object.

```
object[,] virtualCells = new object[Liste.Count, propertyOfContainer.Length];
        for(int j = 0; j < Liste.Count; j++)
        {
            for(int h = 0; h < 12; h++)
            {
                virtualCells[j, h] = Liste[j].GetType().GetProperty(propertyOfContainer[h]).GetValue(Liste[j]);
            }
        }
        
        int lastRow;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(outputWorksheet.Range["L2"].Value2)) { lastRow = 1; }
        else { lastRow = outputWorksheet.Range["L1"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown].Row; }

outputWorksheet.Range[outputWorksheet.Cells[lastRow+1, 1],outputWorksheet.Cells[lastRow + Liste.Count, propertyOfContainer.Length]].Value2 = virtualCells;
```